# Already with Visual C++ 2008, do I need to install Visual C++2005?

Tags: windows, updates, visual-studio

A program that I want to install says it requires Visual C++ 2005. I already have Visual C++ 2008 installed;

1. Am I right to assume that the newer version includes the older as a
   subset?
2. Are there downsides to having two Visual C++ installed, such as could they interfere with each other?
3. If I do need to
   install 2005, would I have to uninstall 2008 first and afterwards
   reinstall it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Nope, that some of the 2008 redistributables are smaller than some of the 2005 ones. The could not possibly contain everything and more that was in the earlier versions.
2. No downsides other than some minimal space taken up
3. Nope

Here is a list of some of the C++ redistributables I have installed:

[image]

Comment: I hate visual C++ so much for this